# Scriptella: ResourceException with Jaybird

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scriptella, jaybird

I'm very newbie with Linux/Java/Scriptella and I'm trying a jdbc connection with scriptella on a Firebird local database, but I'm receiving the following errors:

```
2-dic-2013 1.03.34 <INFO> Execution Progress.Initializing properties: 1%
2-dic-2013 1.03.34 <GRAVE> Script /home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/prova_per_scriptella.etl execution failed.
javax/resource/ResourceException
2-dic-2013 1.03.34 <GRAVE> Scriptella bug report. Submit to issue tracker.
Scriptella version: 1.1
Exception:
scriptella.execution.EtlExecutorException: javax/resource/ResourceException
    at scriptella.execution.EtlExecutor.execute(EtlExecutor.java:190)
    at scriptella.tools.launcher.EtlLauncher.execute(EtlLauncher.java:276)
    at scriptella.tools.launcher.EtlLauncher.launch(EtlLauncher.java:193)
    at scriptella.tools.launcher.EtlLauncher.main(EtlLauncher.java:321)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/ResourceException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at scriptella.core.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:53)
    at scriptella.core.ConnectionManager.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:70)
    at scriptella.core.Session.<init>(Session.java:51)
    at scriptella.execution.EtlExecutor.prepare(EtlExecutor.java:248)
    at scriptella.execution.EtlExecutor.execute(EtlExecutor.java:178)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.ResourceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    ... 10 more
```

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx.

I start scriptella via console in directory /home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/ with the command scriptella/scriptella-1.1/bin/scriptella.sh -debug "prova_per_scriptella.etl"
My ETL file prova_per_scriptella.etl contains the following rows:

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
  <description>Prova connessione Firebird</description>
  <connection
    id="fb_destination"
    driver="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver"
    url="jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/db/jatrofa.fdb"
    user="user"
    password="password"
    classpath="/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/jaybird/Jaybird-2.2.3JDK_1.6/jaybird-2.2.3.jar"
  />
</etl>
```

The env var $_SCRIPTELLA_CP of batch command scriptella/scriptella-1.1/bin/scriptella.sh results in

```
:/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/scriptella/scriptella-1.1/lib/commons-jexl.jar:
/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/scriptella/scriptella-1.1/lib/commons-logging.jar:
/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/scriptella/scriptella-1.1/lib/jaybird-2.2.3.jar:
/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/scriptella/scriptella-1.1/lib/jsqlparser-0.8.0.jar:
/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/scriptella/scriptella-1.1/lib/scriptella-core.jar:
/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/scriptella/scriptella-1.1/lib/scriptella-drivers.jar:
/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/scriptella/scriptella-1.1/lib/scriptella-tools.jar:
/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/scriptella/scriptella-1.1/lib/sqlsheet-6.5.jar
```

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you probably miss additional J2EE classes on classpath. Try downloading mini-j2ee.jar from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/ and adding it to classpath attribute in etl.xml:

```
classpath="/path/to/mini-j2ee.jar:/home/maurizio/Scrivania/JATROPHA/applicazioni/jaybird/Jaybird-2.2.3JDK_1.6/jaybird-2.2.3.jar"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it is functioning... I've found mini-j2ee.jar in Jaybird-2.1.6JDK_1.4.zip. Extracted and inserted in lib directory of scriptella.

Comment: Beg your pardon for later accept. have another question (I hope is not off-topic): there are some tools to detect the missing jar (or other libs)? Thanks a lot

Comment: `mini-j2ee.jar` is deprecated, see the [Jaybird 2.2 releasenotes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.3/release_notes.html#__RefHeading__3644_1575618738)

Comment: @M.Alfani You can use Maven to handle the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the required dependency `connector-api-1.5.jar`, or you need to use `jaybird-full-2.2.3.jar` (which includes both the normal Jaybird and connector-api). See the [releasenotes of Jaybird 2.2.3](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.3/release_notes.html#__RefHeading__8761_1080388197)

Comment: Thanks: I will change my script.

Comment: Same problem for me with a standalone usage of Jayway, it seems that the maven project is missing the dependency, so here is my working pom.xml extract , if it helps:   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.11</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
   <artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.5</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @pdem That dependency is included in the [Jaybird POM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/firebirdsql/jdbc/jaybird-jdk18/2.2.11/jaybird-jdk18-2.2.11.pom), so I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.